# how to select top row from a variable using sql server 2008?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

**Can we select top rows from variable value In sql server 2008?.like this.**

```
    declare @rows int=2;
    select top @rows * from table_name;
-- instead of select top 2 * from table_name;
```

Comment: When you use TOP you also need to specify ORDER BY. Otherwise you have no way to ensure which rows will be returned.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You were almost there.

```
declare @rows int=2;
select top (@rows) * from table_name;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also try this one.

```
declare @rows int=2;
declare @query varchar(200)= 'select top ' + cast(@rows as varchar(4))+ ' * from TBLB_Order';
exec (@query);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
declare @rows int=2;
select top @rows percent * from table_name;
```